# Increasing speed of a for loop through a List and dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, performance, numpy, dataframe, vectorization

Currently I am dealing with a massive amount of Data in the original form of a list through combination. I am running conditions on each set of list through a for loop. Problem is this small for loop is taking hours with the data. I'm looking to optimize the speed by changing some functions or vectorizing it.

I know one of the biggest NO NOs is don't do Pandas or Dataframe operations in for loops but I need to sum up the columns and organize it a little to get what I want. It seems unavoidable.

So you have a better understanding, each list looks something like this when its thrown into a dataframe:

```
0
                 Name     Role  Cost  Value
0      Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
1  Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
2          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
3        Greg Ritcher  Lookout   200     25

                 Name     Role  Cost  Value
4      Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
5  Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
6          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
7         Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30
```

This is the current loop, any ideas?

```
for element in itertools.product(*combine_list):
   combo = list(element)
   df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(combo).reshape(-1,11))
   df[[2,3]] = df[[2,3]].apply(pd.to_numeric)

   if (df[2].sum()) <= 5000 and (df[3].sum()) > 190:
       df2 = pd.concat([df2, df], ignore_index=True)
```

Couple things I've done that have sliced off some time but not enough.
`*df[2].sum() to df[2].values.sum`----its faster

*where the concat is in the if statement I've tried using append and also adding the dataframe together as a list...concat is actually 2 secs faster normally or it will end up being about the same speed.

*by the `.apply(pd.to_numeric)` changed it to `.astype(np.int64)` its faster as well.

I'm currently looking at PYPY and Cython as well but I want to start here first before I go through the headache.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: can you do the numeric computation in numpy? i mean before entering the data into a dataframe? because it will be about 10 to 100 times faster usually. i had a procedure that took 4 seconds with a dataframe and only 0.2 seconds with numpy. Try to see if you can use only numpy for the calculation themselves

Comment: Thanks for the input I'm currently trying to convert as much as a can to numpy and just throw it in a dataframe after all the computations and possibly use cython and its memoryview capabilities and see where it takes me.

Comment: @LiorT Numpy worked Thanks - For those looking for answers.....while running a loop of anysort try to do the numeric calculation in numpy it literally went from 5 minutes to 3 seconds to run.